# Should we have vertical integration (auto-login)?

Tags: discussion, login

I've had some problems with the auto-login entering the chat, which got me thinking... why would that be necessary?

You have the main site, the meta, the related chat and the related blog, and why would it be necessary to login to each and every one of them? These could be features of one application.

**Edit:** With vertical integration, I mean on one SE subdomain. Say StackOverflow, you'd want to be able to use all the features (meta, chat, blog, whatnot) without loggin in.

At this moment, if you are active on four subdomains, you'd have to log in sixteen times! Every time you change browser, bang, one login and fifteen auto-logins (if they work)!
**End Edit**

[The problem I'm having is on one computer where auto-login doesn't work for the chat, so I'll have to logout globally, and login to reset the auto-login feature.]

Is there a compelling reason why these features aren't integrated in the SE experience (apart from the obvious fact some have their own domains)?

Comment: I don't have this problem, and since it seems like you only have the problem on one machine...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that's not the point I'm trying to make. Everybody has to 'login' to chat, meta and blog when they use it for the first time. I think that's unnecessary.

Comment: Why? What if I want to use different logins on different SE sites? For example I may not want to post as my real name on careers (or just in careers chat). I think this is annoying for you because you have one machine where it doesn't work reliably. For most of us, I don't really think your proposal solves a real problem. How many times are you using one of these features for the first time? (Again, on the machines where it isn't broken, which is a different issue.)

Comment: +1 - I have this problem with chat all the time, and I don't know why.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I've edited the question to clarify what I mean with vertical. Ah, it's not a proposal, it's a question.

Comment: @ire_and_curses, this should be solved with the described method; global logout, then login. If you keep having these problems, open a [support] question about it.